# Select the records where ID is in different table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. Below is the structure:

```
Student : SID,SNAME
Subject : SUID,SUNAME
Rid : SID,SUID
```

the result of the query should be :

```
SNAME   SUNAME
```

Comment: A simple JOIN will help you.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Well, technically *two* simple joins.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select st.SNAME
,      sj.SUNAME
from   Rid r
       inner join Student st on r.SID  = st.SID
       inner join Subject sj on r.SUID = sj.SUID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two tables and a relationship table. The relationship (Rid) table is the one that *relates* the other two (Student and Subject). You must search the Rid records where the Student and the Subject are joined:

```
SELECT s.sname, sb.suname 
FROM student s, subject sb, rid r
WHERE s.sid = r.sid AND sb.suid = r.suid;
```

or with *New Style*

```
SELECT s.SNAME, sb.SUNAME
FROM Rid r
INNER JOIN Student s on r.SID = s.SID
INNER JOIN Subject sb on r.SUID = sb.SUID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
select st.SNAME, sj.SUNAME
from Rid r
left join Student st on r.SID = st.SID
left join Subject sj on r.SUID = j.SUID
```